# Bootstrap custom styled checkbox is triggering click event twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

When using Bootstrap with React it is triggering custom styled checkbox's click event twice.
One for rowClicked and another for checkboxClicked. This occurs only when im using bootstrap custom styled checkbox. Default checkbox doesn't have this issue.

How do we stop custom styled checkbox triggering event twice?

Example: https://codepen.io/my-sandbox-online/pen/OJVVdOB

Code:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkboxClicked = this.checkboxClicked.bind(this);
    this.rowClicked = this.rowClicked.bind(this);
   }

  checkboxClicked (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('clicked on checkbox');
  }

  rowClicked (e) {
    console.log('clicked on row');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>Names</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr onClick={(e) => this.rowClicked(e)}>
              <td>
              <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
                <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="test"
                onClick={(e) => this.checkboxClicked(e)}
                />
                <label className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="test"></label>
              </div>
              </td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr onClick={(e) => this.rowClicked(e)}>
              <td><input type="checkbox" onClick={(e) => this.checkboxClicked(e)} /></td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: @qiAlex So how do we stop custom styled checkbox triggering event twice?

Answer (score 0):

Answer and a bit of explanation:

1. `<input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="test"/>` is hidden, so we actually click on the `label`
2. when we handle click on a hidden checkbox - there is no way to catch it before the `row` will handle event, so
3. `onClick` moving from `checkbox` to the `label`, to handle events before the `row`.
4. I'm not very familiar with react, so I don't know the better way to suppress event than, `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();`
5. event is suppressed and now `row` is not involved anymore, unfortunately, neither is `checkbox`. it's value is not updated, because we suppressed an event propagation.
6. checking if target of the event is `label`, selecting the label target and toggling the value.
7. profit )

Working example:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkboxClicked = this.checkboxClicked.bind(this);
    this.rowClicked = this.rowClicked.bind(this);
   }

  checkboxClicked (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (e.target.tagName === 'LABEL') {
      const checkbox = document.querySelector(`#${e.target.htmlFor}`);
      if (checkbox) {
        checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
      }
    }

    console.log('clicked on checkbox');
  }

  rowClicked (e) {
    console.log('clicked on row');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>&nbsp;</th>
              <th>Names</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr onClick={(e) => this.rowClicked(e)}>
              <td>
              <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox my-1 mr-sm-2">
                <input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="test"
                />
                <label onClick={(e) => this.checkboxClicked(e)} className="custom-control-label" htmlFor="test"></label>
              </div>
              </td>
              <td>Row 1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr onClick={(e) => this.rowClicked(e)}>
              <td><input type="checkbox" onClick={(e) => this.checkboxClicked(e)} /></td>
              <td>Row 2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happen because if we use bootstrap custom styled checkbox, the actual checkbox u see in your screen is not :

```
<input type="checkbox" className="custom-control-input" id="test"
            onClick={(e) => this.checkboxClicked(e)}
```

but its javascript made checkbox (i think its made from div) ...
and therefore when u click the checkbox, the row click will be triggered first ...
and then javascript belong to bootstrap will trigger the original checkbox checked event, and checkboxClicked will be called.

while on original checkbox without boostrap custom style, it will trigger the original checkbox checked event, and checkboxClicked will be called.

for solution, may be we should remove the rowclick event, its not a good idea to put click in the row where another child's element have click event, its like putting link inside a link which wont work with regular HTML.

or another way, if u insist to put the rowclick event, may be we can use e.target.type or we can use data- and doing validation.